# `using()` on a stream returned from a method

Tags: c#, using

Assume I have a string class with a method `ToStream()`.

```c#
class FooBar
{
    pubic Stream ToStream( )
    {
        byte[ ] barFooBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes( this.BarFoo );
        return new MemoryStream( barFooBytes );
    }
}
```

Now assume I have a class getting this stream.

```c#
class BarFoo
{
    pubic void DoCrazyStuff( )
    {
        using( Stream fooBarStream = ( new FooBar( ) ).ToStream( ) )
        {
            // Doing some really crazy stuff!
        }
    }
}
```

Does it still make sense to use a `using` outside of the method creating the stream?

**Hint:**
This is not an actual real life scenario. It's a pure technical question of interest. So this code is minified just to clarify the question.

Comment: Why `new Foobar()` - why not make the `ToStream` method a static method if it doesn't need persistent instance state?

Comment: Assume I can create a `Action<List<MyAwesomeClass>>`, does it make sense ? The only correct answer is:   **It depends**.  We need to know more details in order to give an educated guess.

Comment: Also, I recommend against returning a `Byte[]` as a `MemoryStream` if the data is natively a `Byte[]` unless you have a constraint or use-case elsewhere that requires it. If the data is primarily a `Byte[]` but some consumer needs it as a `Stream` then wrapping it in a `MemoryStream` should be the consumer's responsibility, not the producer's.

Comment: Can we not have swear words in questions please, thanks

Comment: @dai The question is not about the instanziation of `FooBar`. It's about the `using` on the stream as a return value. And this snippet just shows what I meant.

@liam Where did I use swear words?

Comment: @fabjan I just wanted to know if the using is working correctly in this case.

Comment: @fabjan @codecaster Where this question is a duplicate of the asked one? These are two completely different setups of using streams and `using`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `using`/`IDisposable`, the important question to be able to answer at any time is "who *owns* this object?". In this instance, the `ToStream` method has to return a `Stream`, so whilst it owned the object whilst it was running, it and the class it's part of assume no further responsibility for it. It therefore doesn't `Dispose` or wrap it in a `using`.

Therefore, we can decide that ownership of the object has been passed back to the caller of the `ToStream` method. So, as the new owner of the object, it's your responsibility to wrap it in a `using`, manually `Dispose` of it or pass the ownership on to something else.

---

As [John's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53516003/15498) and the comments below it point out, a `MemoryStream`, specifically, doesn't significantly benefit from `Dispose` being called on it (the buffer remains allocated). However, it implements `Dispose` because it inherits from `Stream` and contractually, all that your `ToStream` method promised to provide was a `Stream`, not a `MemoryStream`, so `using`/`Dispose` is correct for the caller.

Comment: I hope that C# 9.0 adds something like Rust's ownership and borrowing semantics because that solves this problem entirely.